# Where do I get 'httr' for R version 2.15.2

Tags: linux, r

Hi, all.
The 'httr' file that `CRAN` website provides only works on those Rs with versions higher than 3.0. I have a R version `2.15.2`. Where can I get 'httr' for my version of R?
Thanks!

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Sincerely, Alicia.

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/httr/

Comment: You **really** want to update R to 3.1.0.  You are now two years out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the old archives of a package from cran. For `httr` the archive is at cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/httr . For projects on github some developers will have tagged releases. `httr` has the following releases https://github.com/hadley/httr/releases . You can install a package from github using the `install_github` function from the `devtools` package.

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/httr", ref = "httr-0.2")
```

would install the release tagged 'httr-0.2'

Comment: I went to the url you've kindly told me and download all of the packages for httr it offered. I downloaded them on my R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/2.15 folder, and extracted one of the tar.gz packages. Then on my R prompt, I typed install.packages("httr"). I get "package 'httr' is not available (for R version 2.15.2)." I tried for httr packages of 0.2, 0.1.1, 0.1 versions and they all result with the same error. What must I do?

Comment: Use `install.packages('path.to/httr_0.2.tar.gz', repos = NULL)`

Comment: I followed you instructions and it says dependencies 'RCurl,' ;stringr,' 'digest' aren't there for installation. Arg... I'll get those and hope it works! Thanks!